# Is this the correct truth table to determine whether or not to execute an interrupt in a RISC V system?

Tags: interrupts, hdl, risc-v

I'm working on implementing the privileged RISC V ISA, which can be found [here](https://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa/).

I'm looking at the bottom of page 20, and the interrupt conditions are stated very confusingly:

> Global interrupt-enable bits, MIE, SIE, and UIE, are provided for each
>   privilege mode.  These bits are primarily used to guarantee atomicity
>   with respect to interrupt handlers in the current privilege mode.
>
> *The global x IE bits are located in the low-order bits of mstatus, allowing them to be atomically set or cleared with a single CSR instruction.*
>
> When a hart is executing in privilege mode x,
>   interrupts are globally enabled when x IE=1 and globally disabled when
>   x IE=0. Interrupts for lower-privilege modes, wx, are
>   always globally enabled regardless of the setting of the
>   higherprivilege mode’s global y IE bit. Higher-privilege-level code
>   can use separate per-interrupt enable bits to disable selected
>   higher-privilege-mode interrupts before ceding control to a
>   lower-privilege mode.

With this description, I have made the following truth table which determines whether or not a certain interrupt will be execute based upon the  MIE, SIE, and UIE bits, and the current privilege mode. This is confusing because it seems like while execution as a user, the supervisor won't take interrupts of a higher privilege level... Is that correct?

[image]

is this truth table correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the truth table above is correct, and verifiable by the text.

Note that if you want to disable a higher level interrupt while running in a lower level mode, the interrupts can be disabled on an individual basis.

Comment: I think you're using 'Answer' on this site like 'Reply' is used on other discussion sites. Although well-intended, this is a comment and not an answer. It will most likely be deleted but you can delete it yourself before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM what's wrong? it's correct, and uses a first hand source

Comment: Your answer needs to contain some explanations rather than just firing off a one-line solution exam-style. It should be written clearly enough to teach future readers. It appears you've since edited it beyond the 'yes it is' it originally was.

Comment: @TonyM so what would you suggest I put in to teach future readers?

Comment: I have no suggestion on the detail of your own answer. I have tried to help you avoid deletion votes. I did not mark it for deletion and deletion comes after multiple votes.

Comment: Well I welcome anyone else who may have suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you could consider any improvements of your own. That may avoid any future deletion votes and, more importantly, may produce a better answer. I'll leave you you to your thoughts and wish you well.